# Parallel execution of PHP

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I have a php script file `test1.php`

```
 <?php
echo "hello\n"
?>
```

When i try to run the `php` through command line using following code only one php process run and other php process is stopped.
We can see only one `hello` is printed.
***Why other process is stopped ?***

```
[root@home usr]# php -f test1.php & php -f test1.php
[30] 20817
 hello
[root@home usr]# 
[30]+  Stopped                 php -f test1.php
```

PS:

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Putting a `&` after a command on the command line puts it in the background. So the first command has probably finished running in the background and that is why you don't see the output.

Comment: That's strange. Just tried that on ubuntu system and everything works as expected, test1.php gets executed twice.

Comment: You should use `&&`: `# php -f test1.php && php -f test1.php`

Comment: @ConstantinGuay `&&` that will not run them in parallel instead it will run it one by one.. i want to run them parallel

Comment: @maxhb mine in centos 7

Comment: Ok, maybe to test your code you should not print result but write it in a file instead. If the second php run in background you should see it.

Comment: @jeroen we can executed the same .php script a number of times, the processes are independent and conceptually there shouldn't be any issue since there will be 2 different process ids ..right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Right, but if you want to measure if they are working, you should have them write to a file for example as processes in the background will probably not output to the terminal. They might, but that could depend on your setup.

Comment: @jeroen i guess creating a .sh file would do the job. Will have to write this execute command twice and there will be 2 processes at the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts get executed in parallel.

Try this modified version of a test script:

```
<?php
// Read first command line argument
$delay = (int) $argv[1];
// Wait for $delay seconds
sleep($delay);
// Output some message
echo "Result after $delay seconds\n";
```

If you invoke this script via `php hello.php 3 & php hello.php 1` you will see that the first call will run for 3 seconds and print some output while the second call will only run for 1 second and print some output before the first call sends output:

```
root@httpserver:/tmp# php hello.php 3 & php hello.php 1
[1] 15991
Result after 1 seconds
root@httpserver:/tmp# Result after 3 seconds
```

If you are looking for other ways of parallel script execution you should have a look at this article https://d-mueller.de/blog/parallel-processing-in-php/